# Proving a bijection with the use of residue classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I was given this challenge problem on an assignment and am having a difficult time understanding how to work with residue classes (denoted $[n]$):

Prove that $f : Z_3->Z_3$ defined by $f([n]) = [2n]$ is a bijection. Would this work for $Z_6 -> Z_6$?

I am confused on how to map a $[n]$ to $[2n]$. I believe this would not be possible for $Z_6$ but need help with the fundamental understanding of the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know what $f([0]), f([1]), $ and $f([2])$ are in $\mathbb Z_3$?  What would $f([0])$ and $f([3])$ be in $\mathbb Z_6$?

Comment: f([0]) = [2(0)] = [0].
f([1]) = [2(1)] = [2].
f([2]) = [2(2)] = [4] = [1]?

Then in Z6 it would be
f([0]) = [2(0)] = [0].
f([3]) = [2(3)] = [6] = [0]?

I think I'm seeing it, but would like to ensure the above is correct.

Comment: You are correct!  Multiplication by $2$ is not invertible when the modulus is even

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out when prompted in comments,

$f([0])=[0]$, $f([1])=[2]$ , and $f([2])=[1]$ in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$,
so $f$ is a bijection for $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

However, in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, $f([0])=[0]$ and $f([3])=[0]$, so $f$ is not a bijection for $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.

(Multiplication by $2$ is not invertible with even moduli such as $6$.)

Answer (score 0):

There are three elements:

$[0] = \{.....,-9,-6,-3,0, 3,6,9,.....\}=\{\text{all the integers of the form: }3k\}$.

$[1]= \{......, -8,-5, -2, 1, 4, 7, 10 ....\}=\{\text{all the integers of the form: }3k+1\}$.

$[2]=\{......,-7,-5,-1,2,5,8,11....\}=\{\text{all the integers of the form: }3k+2\}$.

We can *notate* this elements in in infinite number of ways.  For example.  Take the integer $n= 92$.  $92$ is in one of the forms $3k; 3k+1$ or $3k+2$.  it happens to be that $92 = 3*30 + 2$ so $92 \in [2]$.  And we can write $[2]$ as $[92]$.  $[92] = [2]$.

$[n] = \{\text{all the integer of the form: }3k + r\text{ where }r\text{ is the remainder of }n\text{ when divided by }3\}$.

So $[1]$ and $[4]$ and $[7]$ and $[3487]$ are all the exact same thing.  They are all the same set of integers: $\{......,-8,-5,-2,1,4,7,....., 3481,3484,3487,3490,3493,....\}$.

So you have a set of three element:  $[0], [1],[2]$

You have a function that maps $[n]\mapsto [2n]$.

So $[0] \mapsto [2\cdot 0] = [0]$.

And $[1]\mapsto [2\cdot 1] = [2]$.

And $[2]\mapsto [2\cdot 2] = [\color{red}4] = \{.....,-8, -5, -2, \color{green}1, \color{red}4, 7, 10,13,....\} = [\color{green}1 ]$.

And so that's it, that's the function.  It is the function:

$[0]\mapsto [0]; [1]\mapsto[2]; [2]\mapsto [1]$.

Is that a bijection?  Well, its a well defined function:  Every element of $\mathbb Z_3$ is mapped to on specific element of $\mathbb Z_3$.  It's onto:  Every element of $\mathbb Z_3$ is mapped to.  And it is one-to-one: $f([n]) = f([m]) \iff [n] = [m]$... that there is only *one* value that mapst to $[0]$ (namely $[0]$) and there is only *one* value that maps to $[1]$ (namely $[2]$) and there is only *one* value that maps to $[2]$ (namely $[1])$.

SO it is a one-to-one onto function from $\mathbb Z_3 \to \mathbb Z_3$.

Hence it is a bijection.

......

Would this work for $\mathbb Z_6$?

Well there are $6$ elements.

$[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]$.

And $[n]\mapsto [2n]$ would map the six elements the following way:

$[0]\mapsto [2\cdot 0] = [0]$

$[1]\mapsto [2\cdot 1] = [2]$

$[2]\mapsto [2\cdot 2] = [4]$

$[3]\mapsto [3\cdot 2] = [6] = \{......-12, -6, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24.....\} = [1\times 6 + 0 ] = [0]$.

$[4]\mapsto [4\cdot 2] = [8] = [1\times 6 + 2] = \{.....-10,-4, 2, 8, 14, 20,28...\} = [2]$

$[5]\mapsto [5\cdot 2] = [10] = [1\times 6 + 4] = \{.... -8, -2, 4, 10, 16,22, 28\}=[4]$.

And that's the function.  It is the function: $[0]\mapsto [0];[1]\mapsto [2];[2]\mapsto [4];[3]\mapsto [0];[4]\mapsto [2];[5]\mapsto [4];$

Is that function onto? Is it one to one?

More importantly.... is there a way I could have figured that all out without having to list all the elements or write out the entire function?